# 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'AsAsyncOperation'

Tags: async-await, uwp

If I want to expose this method from a UWP class library

```csharp
public async Task<int> PlaySound(SoundGroup soundGroup, int index, Duration duration)
```

then I need to create a wrapper thus

```csharp
public IAsyncOperation<int> PlaySoundAsync(SoundGroup soundGroup, int index, Duration duration)
{
    return PlaySound(soundGroup, index, duration).AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

But the same trick fails with this method

```csharp
public async Task PreLoadSoundPlayers()
```

because this

```csharp
public IAsyncOperation PreLoadSoundPlayersAsync()
{
    return PreLoadSoundPlayers().AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

gives the error

> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'AsAsyncOperation' and no extension method 'AsAsyncOperation' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found

What is the correct pattern for exposing asynchronous methods that do not have a data return type in a UWP class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - I needed to use actions instead of operations.

```csharp
public IAsyncAction PreLoadSoundPlayersAsync()
{
    return PreLoadSoundPlayers().AsAsyncAction();
}
```